Why is my vue application update route but not router-view
I'm having a hard time understanding why my router-view is not being updated in root template of App.vue while route is being correctly changed.
Here is my router, it correctly navigates to /:user page and updates view accordingly but when i try to navigate from MainUserView navbar to UserProfile it changes route to /some_user/profile but do not render new view.
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router"

import MainView from "@/views/MainView.vue";
import UserProfile from "@/views/Profile.vue";
import MainUserView from "@/views/MainUserView.vue";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "home",
        component: MainView
    },
    {
        path: "/:user",
        name: "User View",
        component: MainUserView,
        children: [
            {
                path: "profile",
                name: "User profile view",
                component: UserProfile
            }
        ]
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
});


export default router;

Here is my App.vue
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <MainView v-if="!user || user !== 'lukasz' && user !== 'karolina'"/>

    <navbar v-if="user"></navbar>
    <section class="section">
      <router-view/>
    </section>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import MainView from './views/MainView.vue'
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {

    }
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.state.user;
    }
  },
  components: {
    Navbar,
    MainView,
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch("initializeUser");
  },
  created(){
     console.log("DUPA2")
  }
}
</script>

And navbar template from which I'm routing to UserProfile
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar " :class="{'is-danger': user === 'karolina', 'is-info' : user === 'lukasz'}">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <router-link to="/" class="navbar-item" @click="clearUser">
          <strong>Choose again</strong>
        </router-link>
        <a class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbar-menu">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-menu" id="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <router-link to="/send-message" class="navbar-item"
          >Send message
          </router-link
          >
          <!-- <router-link :to="{name: 'User View', params: {user: 'lukasz'}}"> -->
          <router-link :to="{name: 'User profile view', params: {user: user}}" class="navbar-item"
          >Your Profile
          </router-link
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NavbarComponent",
  props: {
  },
  methods: {
    clearUser() {
      this.$store.commit("clearUser");
    }
  },
  computed:{
    user() {
      return this.$store.state.user;
    }
  }
}
</script>

I tried to move navbar from App.vue to maybe MainUserView but it did not help. Also displaying just router-view inside App.vue do not help so i assume the problem lays in different place.
Thanks for any help!

children routes are for when the direct parent (MainUserView) has it's own <router-view> component.  It doesn't look like that's the case here.  It's likely you want to define a route with path /:user/profile and not as a child route.

{
    path: "/:user",
    children: [
        {
            path: "",
            name: "User View",
            component: MainUserView,
        },
        {
            path: "profile",
            name: "User profile view",
            component: UserProfile
        }
    ]
}

When dealing with Named Routes, you usually name the children routes
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Thank you so much, I did not know about this before

Learn from Each Other, Progress Together
